# How can i change the innerHTML of a list item?

Tags: javascript, html

ok so i have this code of HTML

```
<ul class="wsite-menu-default">
  <li id="lis1" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-1" style="position: relative;">
<a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Home
</a>
</li>
<li id="lis2" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-2" style="position: relative;">
<a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Images
</a>
</li>
<li id="lis3" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-3" style="position: relative;">
<a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Facilities
</a>
</li>
<li id="lis4" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-4" 
style="position: relative;">
<a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Contact
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And what i am trying to do is to change the text of the firt list item "Home" to "Main" without affecting the functionality of the element. I have tried many things so far. However, this is the last thing i tried:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("lis1").innerHTML = "<a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">Main</a>";
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to escape `"` or use `'` to wrap the whole string:
`el.innerHTML = '<a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">Main</a>';`

Comment: Could you make that a runnable Stack Snippet? That alone should help you to sort out one or two issues.

Comment: Try this : <script>
document.getElementById("lis1").innerHTML = '<a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">Main</a>';
</script>

Comment: @webdeb thanks a lot! It worked! However i can not find my mistake i did also put (" ") around the string.

Comment: You used the same quotes marks inside and outside. So your string stopped after `..href="`

Answer (score 3):

Change just it's `textContent`, not whole `innerHTML`.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('#lis1 a');
    elem.textContent = 'Main';
```

```html
<ul class="wsite-menu-default">
  <li id="lis1" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-1" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Home
</a>
  </li>
  <li id="lis2" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-2" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Images
</a>
  </li>
  <li id="lis3" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-3" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Facilities
</a>
  </li>
  <li id="lis4" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap  wsite-nav-4" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-item" style="position: relative;">
    Contact
</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```